# Why doesn't this RSpec stub work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

i have created an rspec test like :

```
    it "should redirect to '/tavern' with an error if user already has a tavern quest" do
        user = mock('User')
        user.stub(:has_tavern_quest).and_return(true)
        post :new_quest, :quest_type => 3
        flash[:error].should_not be_nil
        response.should redirect_to tavern_path
    end
```

Then, i wrote the controller part :

```
# check if user already has a tavern quest
if current_user.has_tavern_quest?
    flash[:error] = 'You already have a quest to finish !'
    redirect_to tavern_path and return 
end
```

And the model part :

```
  def has_tavern_quest?
    TavernQuest.exists?(self.id)
  end
```

I would expect that the test succeeds, now but i get :

```
  1) TavernController POST '/quest/' to get a new quest of quest_type == 3 should redirect to '/tavern' with an error if user already has a tavern quest
     Failure/Error: flash[:error].should_not be_nil
       expected: not nil
            got: nil
     # ./spec/controllers/tavern_controller_spec.rb:29
```

Do i have a mistake somewhere ?

THE MACRO FOR LOGIN USER :

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = :user
      @user = Factory.create(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
it "should redirect to '/tavern' with an error if user already has a tavern quest" do
  controller.stub_chain(:current_user,:has_tavern_quest?).and_return(true)
  post :new_quest, :quest_type => 3
  flash[:error].should_not be_nil
  response.should redirect_to tavern_path
end
```

Comment: Awesome that works great ! You really rock, that had me for quite some time. I still don't understand why my last example would not work, but yours works just great.

Comment: `controller` returns the test controller instance created by RSpec. You can call methods on it to set up the test conditions. `stub_chain` replaces the implentation of `current_user.has_tavern_quest?` so that it returns true when the controller action is called. For more info, see the RSpec docs https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-0/docs/stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods, and the Rails testing guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Answer (score 1):

Your mock doesn't do anything... perhaps you meant to use it somewhere?

I personally dislike mocking in this case and feel it's obfuscation. If you are using Devise you could use [their test helpers](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee/blob/master/spec/support/devise.rb#L1-3) to [sign in as a user](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee/blob/master/spec/controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb#L8).

Comment: Doesn't it create a stub so that has_tavern_quest returns true ?

Comment: @SpyrosP: no, you're mocking the string "User" which isn't used anywhere. Perhaps you meant to use `mock_model` and then sign in as that user?

Comment: I actually already use devise helpers and sign in works(i've tested on other tests). This one, does not. I changed to mock_model and still get the same effect though :/

Comment: @SpyrosP your mock model != current_user in your controller. You have to sign in that mock user using the devise helpers as mentioned by Ryan. The sign in will set current_user to your mock user.

Comment: ok, i change the stub with a factory, that works for sure (i checked it with @user.username.should == 'test3' and it works ok). However, still the same error. The post is ok because i've used it in previous tests. Is @user.stub(:has_tavern_quest).and_return(true) correct ? It's the ony thing i can think of. I seriously don't understand why i get nil here. Btw, this user is logged in, i've used it with a macro login_user as devise tests specify and i've already tried it in previous tests.

Comment: i'm also editing the post to add the macro if that helps. Btw, i've also tried it with @user.stub(:has_tavern_quest?).and_return(true), which i actually think is the correct way.